# Can modulus function present in a particular solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponential-function, absolute-value

> Particular solution of $2ye^{\tfrac{x}{y}}dx+\Big(y-2xe^{\tfrac{x}{y}}\Big)dy=0$, $x=0$ when $y=1$

**Attempt**

Put $x=vy$
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}}\\
\frac{dx}{dy}=v+y\frac{dv}{dy}=v-\frac{1}{2e^{v}}\implies y\frac{dv}{dy}=-\frac{1}{2e^{v}}\\
\implies\int2e^{v}dv=-\int\frac{dy}{y}\implies2e^{v}=-\log|y|+C\\
2e^{v}+\log|y|=C\implies\color{red}{2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log|y|=C}
$$
$x=0$ when $y=1\implies C=2$
$$
{2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log|y|=2}
$$
which is what is given in my reference as solution, but can the modulus function be involved in the particular solution of a differential equation ?

Or do I need to eliminate the solution $2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log({\text{-}y})=2$ ?

Comment: it should be $$x'-\frac xy=-\frac 12$$

Comment: @Isham srry editing mistake, bracket got misplaced. pls check.

Comment: no problem ss1729.....

Comment: @Isham edited Op. hope it better explains my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log|y|=C\implies\begin{cases}2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log y=C\\
2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log(\text{-}y)=C\end{cases}
$$
The condition "$x=0$ when $y=1$" is only applicable to case 1 as $y=1>0$. Thus,
$$
2e^{\frac{0}{1}}+\log 1=C\implies C=2\\
2e^{\tfrac{x}{y}}+\log y=2
$$
is the particular solution when $x=0;y=1$.